# SharePoint 2019: One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas

Tags: calculated-column, 2019

I keep getting this error message

> One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas

but I don't exactly understand what it is saying. I see this error message referenced in other questions on the internet, but what exactly this error is is never addressed. Could someone please unpack it for me a little more? Also, is it known if this error message is associated with some kind of bug or issue with SharePoint 2019? I keep getting this error message whenever I try to create a Calculated Column. Effectively, I am building new sites based on old sites, so I know the formulas work. There seems to be no rhyme or reason for why I am getting this error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior as only certain data types can be used in formulas.

Not all data types can be used in Formulas in SharePoint, only columns of the following data types can be referenced in a formula: single line of text, number, currency, date and time, choice, yes/no, and calculated.